# Electron crashes when making an HTTPS request inside an addeventlistener callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, crash, electron

I am making a basic Electron app that logs a user into a system. The username and password are provided from the user via form text inputs, and when the "login" button is clicked, the program makes a couple of https requests, signing the user in.

I have an event listener attached to the "login" button that fires when the button is clicked. Its callback function *should* get the entered username and password and make the https requests necessary to sign the user in. However, **when the https requests are inside of the callback function, the renderer process in Electron crashes** (a white screen and "dev tools disconnected" are displayed).

Here is some pseudo-code describing the problem:

```
//This case crashes Electron
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    password = document.getElementById('password').value;

    req = https.request(options, function(res) {
        //Login stuff here, including a post request
        //that sends the username and password to a server
    });
    req.end();
});
```

**When I move the https requests out of the callback function and hardcode the username and password into the program, everything works as expected.**

Pseudo-code for the working case:

```
//This case does not crash Electron
username = "someUsername"
password = "somePassword"

req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    //Login stuff here, including another post request
    //that sends to username and password to a server
});
```

**I want to be able to get the username and password dynamically and make the necessary https requests to sign the user into the system.** I've been searching around for any information about this for awhile now, but I haven't been able to find anyone that is having a similar problem.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RESOLVED**

My button was labeled as "type='submit'" and switching it to "type='button'" solved the problem.